# Call Bluebird Promise function in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I'm new in promises. Im not sure how to write this code in bluebird promises. Can someone explain how this should look with promises?

```
for (var i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {

        var path = '127.0.0.1/getdata/' + i;

        http.get({
            path: path,
        }, (res) => {
          var data = res.resume();
        });
}
```

Thanks for everything

Comment: Are you trying to run the requests in parallel and collect all results in order at the end or are you trying to run them one at a time one after the other?  What is your goal?

Comment: When we ask you clarifying questions, you should respond.  When you leave important details unclear, the only answers that are possible are guesses.  Please answer when people ask you questions.

Comment: My goal is save data from all websites to variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you  just want to collect the results of 10 requests, that don't depend upon one another, then you can launch them all in parallel and let promises collect the results for you.  Since you mentioned Bluebird, you can let Bluebird make promisified versions of the http methods:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = Promise.promisifyAll(require('request'), {multiArgs: true});

var promises = [];
for (var i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
    var path = '127.0.0.1/getdata/' + i;
    promises.push(request.getAsync(path).spread(function(response, body) {
        return body;
    }));
}
Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    // array of results here
}, function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeRequest() {
    var items = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
    return Promise.map(items, function(item) {
        console.log(item);
        return get('/echo/html/');
    });
}
makeRequest().then(function(results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scottjustin5000/bbduj3Lt/)

This approach is using Bluebird's [Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html)

Comment: Thanks, this works. So if I get it, Promise.map is promise loop for function? Cheers

Comment: Promise.map is very similar to Promise.all (native and bluebird's), however Promise.map provides additional options, specifically concurrency.  I demonstrated this technique b/c it is specific to bluebird (Promise.all can be found in native), but too b/c  ["A common use of Promise.map is to replace the .push+Promise.all boilerplate "](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html)